# Use quotes for value inside set within a Update statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below Update table statement that is doing a join..I am not able to see the join result.

```
update #FeesCalculation 
        set BasedOn = A.BasedOn
        from FeeMapping A
        where A.ServiceId = ItemId
```

If I just enter the value directly I am able to see the column being updated.

```
update #FeesCalculation 
            set BasedOn = 'Test'
            from FeeMappingSid A
            where A.ServiceId = ItemId
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing in the first sql query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a proper join

```
update #FeesCalculation 
   set #FeesCalculation.BasedOn = A.BasedOn
  from #FeesCalculation 
  join FeeMappingSid A
    on A.ServiceId = #FeesCalculation.ItemId
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..This is also not working..if I update  set #FeesCalculation.BasedOn = A.BasedOn to  set #FeesCalculation.BasedOn = 'Test' then it updates all the matching rows

Comment: I suspect it is working and you are not testing properly

Comment: OK Thanks..The only change I am doing is adding fixed value and I see the join happening and all the matching rows are getting updated with the static value..When I just use the joining table value then it's not working for some reason.

Comment: I heard you the first time.

Comment: I apologize..You were right I was testing it wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

> I have the below Update table statement that is doing a join.

No, it's not doing a join. I'm amazed either query runs at all. You want this:

```
UPDATE fc
SET fc.BasedOn = fm.BasedOn
FROM #FeesCalculation fc 
INNER JOIN FeeMappingSid fm  ON fm.ServiceId = fc.ItemId
```

Now you've got a join.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..This is also not working..if I update SET fc.BasedOn = fm.BasedOn to SET fc.BasedOn = 'Test' then it updates all the matching rows

Comment: The issue is the quotes around the joined column is not working for some reason.

Comment: Are you adding quotes anywhere? There are no quotes in my answer.

Comment: Nope I am not adding quotes as such anywhere.. i was just trying to replace it with a static value to see if the join is working as expected.

Comment: Honestly I don't know why it is not working..It is a simple join statement.